# Nginx-Ingress fails to rewrite path sometimes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

The error occurs very rarely. The majority of the time the path rewrite works like expected, when the error is triggered people get a `default backend - 404` HTML page as the result. I checked the Nginx-Ingress logs the path is not being rewritten and is passed off to `upstream-default-backend` rather than my service.

Here is my manifest for ingress.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: palette-dev-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /palette/$2
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "stickycookie" # secure cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: "/" 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 50m 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        location = / { 
            return 302 /palette ;
        } 
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.example.cloud
    - dev.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: palette-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /palette(/|$)(.*) 
  - host: dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: palette-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /palette(/|$)(.*)
```

I never personally experienced this error but at least two other people have. From what I was told if you just go to the same URL again it will go away.

I am at a loss here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At what path is the error coming ? Also is your regex working fine for all routes.

Comment: This time it came from /search but I know search has been working normally usually (I just double checked). Here are the Nginx-Ingress logs:
```10.240.0.8 - - [29/Jul/2020:18:00:21 +0000] "GET /search?criteria=%7B%22sortType%22%3A%22SORT_TYPE_RELEVANCY_DESC%22%7D HTTP/2.0" 404 21 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0" 378 0.001 [upstream-default-backend] [] 10.244.0.80:8080 21 0.000 404 2b98e57b460bb1dac3c69c6c994270a6
```

Comment: I think this may be an error in the service I'm running rather than an issue with Nginx-Ingress.

Comment: Can you paste above logs into post, also did you manage to find workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Nginx misconfiguration interacting with our application. Very easy fix once it became known how to trigger it. Previously I was trying to debug this from the logs alone. All that was needed was an update to the Nginx configuration (specifically server-snippet)